# How to connect SQL Server with Unity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

I am trying to store or retrieve an image dynamically using Unity from SQL Server. I am facing issues trying to connect to the SQL Server. How do I connect to the SQL Server?

Comment: First of all try your own code, and if you have any problem, put your code here.

Comment: I think Unity can't be used for that purpose, something else will be needed for getting the data from SqlServer and then use that data with Unity. As an example there's SqlConnection class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: A [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses the `MONO.NET framework`, which is very similar to the `Microsoft.NET framework`. 
This is sample code:

```
public void connect(){
         string connectionString =
             "Server=servername;" +
             "Database=dbname;" +
             "User ID=userid;" +
             "Password=pass;" +
             "Integrated Security=True";

         result = new List<float> ();
         resultCas = new List<DateTime> ();

         using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {
             SqlCommand c; SqlDataReader da; SqlParameter param1; SqlParameter param2; SqlParameter param3; SqlParameter param4;
              conn.Open();
             c = new SqlCommand();
             c.Connection = conn;
             c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             c.CommandText = "commandtext";
             param1 = c.Parameters.Add("@identify",SqlDbType.Int);        
             param1.Value = 1;
             param2 = c.Parameters.Add("@startTime",SqlDbType.DateTime);
             param2.Value = "2010-11-10 07:45:00.000";
             param3 = c.Parameters.Add("@endTime",SqlDbType.DateTime);
             param3.Value = "2010-11-12 10:15:00.000";
             param4 = c.Parameters.Add("@args",SqlDbType.NVarChar);
             param4.Value = "I";
             da = c.ExecuteReader();
             while (da.Read())
             {
                 resultCas.Add(da.GetDateTime(0));
                 result.Add((float)da.GetDouble(1));
             }
         }
     }
```

From Unity, use the `WWW` or `UnityWebRequest` class to communicate with that script and then, you will be able to send and receive information from Unity to the server. There are many examples out there. 
You can also receive data multiple with `json`.

Visit this complete example from [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores) Unity wiki. It shows how to interact with a database in Unity using `php` and `C#` on the server side and `Unity` on the client side.

Hope it Helps.Thanks!